# Chef use node_name variable in JSON role

Tags: json, chef-infra

Is there a way to use NODE_NAME value in a role ?
In fact, I'm writing a base role that is setting nodes hostnames and I wish to use NODE_NAME as "short_hostname".

```
{
   "name": "Chef-RHEL",
   "description": "Chef-RHEL role",
   "json_class": "Chef::Role",
   "default_attributes": {
     "set_fqdn": "*.example.com",
     "system": {
       "timezone": "Europe/Paris",
       "short_hostname": "{NODE_NAME}",
       "domain_name": "example.com"
     }
   },
   "override_attributes": {
   },
   "chef_type": "role",
   "run_list": [
                "recipe[system::default]"
   ],
   "env_run_lists": {
   }
}
```

NODE_NAME is correctly configured in /etc/chef/client.rb.

Thanks a lot !!! :)

Comment: you may try `"#{node.name}" ` I think

Comment: Inside a role..? I think this can't work and needs to be done within a cookbook. Thought the roles are interpreted by the Chef Server..

Comment: @StephenKing was my doubt, I had though roles were retrieved by the chef-client and interpreted after recipes attributes files (to override their level) and then environment, but I can be wrong.

Comment: I'm also not sure as well.. but if we have roles as JSON.. not sure if these can be interpreted through ruby. Probably @coderanger knows :-)

Comment: @StephenKing I'm still unsure, but they are loaded by the chef-client in the order defined [here](https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#attribute-persistence), so I assume interpolation in the attribute itself should work when you use it in a resource (in a ruby context this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible directly, roles are static JSON data only. You can use some kind of string replacement in the recipe code but that requires changes in the cookbook consuming the attribute first.

Comment: Hi @coderanger, thanks a lot ! :-) I'll handle that diffrently :-)